# Enable Audio when connecting to Hyper-V Virtual Machine

Tags: audio, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, hyper-v

I'm running Windows Server 2012 R2 and have two Virtual Machines with on my Hyper-V. One is of Windows 10 and the other is Linux Mint. In both cases I can't get the audio to work because the VMs arent detecting my USB headset or audio jack speakers. I've seen solutions online where changing the settings of RDP work but thats only when actually using RDP to connect. I'm connecting to my VMs directly by double clicking the virtual machine I want to connect to in the Hyper-V Manager window. I don't know how to enable audio when connecting via Hyper-V Manager.

Answer (score 1):

For the Windows 10 machine instance, this is how you enable audio:

1. First, if you connect to your Hyper V Windows 10 instance directly from Hyper-V manager, you will never get audio to work.   The connection through Hyper-V Manager does not support audio.
2. If you want some audio playing through your Windows 10 instance, you will have to run Remote Desktop itself in order to enjoy its audio.   I launch remote desktop via the command line:

   ```
   MSTSC /v:MyWindow10  /f
   ```

   - For MSTSC to work, your Windows 10 instance must have remote desktop enabled. For the Home Version of Windows 10, remote desktop has been disabled by Microsoft. There is nothing that you can do except to purchase  a professional version of Windows 10 so that Remote Desktop will work.
   - To enable remote desktop on your Windows 10 Professional instance, click on Settings.  In the search by text box, enter "Remote".  This will bring up the Remote option. Click Remote  to bring up Remote Desktop. Enable Remote Desktop. It should be disabled by default.
   - You will have to give your Windows 10 instance a name.
     I named mine, MyWindows10. Go to file explorer. click on This PC, this is located on the left panel. Then go to Menu on explorer and click Computer.  This brings up Properties. Click Properties. To give your Windows 10 instance a name, click on Rename this PC button. Give your Windows 10 instance a name. This is the name that Remote Desktop  in step 2 is referring to.
3. By default, your Windows 10 instance should already support audio.   There is nothing else for you to do. But for those folks who are running a Server 2019 instance, you must enable Windows Audio Yourself.   Run Windows Administration Tools | Services. Go down the list of services until you find Windows Audio. Make sure that the Windows Audio process is running. For Windows 10, it should be running. For Server 2019/2016/2012, it should will not be working by default. Set the startup type to automatic and press the start button. Now you can play MP3 files through your Windows 10 instance.
4. Verify that the windows firewall has remote desktop enabled.
   Launch the Windows Firewall. Click on "Allow an app or feature through Windows Defender Firewall." Enable the remote desktop service.